# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in android.os.AsyncTask while using Collections.sort

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am dealing with an Android application that has many async operations taking place all at once.  As such, I am running into a lot of IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions and ConcurrentModificationExceptions in the app.  Most of them are solved by synchronizing methods or ensuring UI operations run on the main UI thread, however this one has me stumped.

In my code I am using an AsyncTask to pull new objects from a local database and refresh the list of objects being displayed in BaseAdapter.  The list of items to be displayed is constantly changing and my refresh method may be called from multiple threads.

The problematic code is pasted below.  The getChat() call returns a list messages which is the part that may constantly change.  To avoid any complications with this, I am creating a new copy of the list before I sort/display the objects using Lists.newLinkedList().

```
        protected CurrentChat doInBackground(final Connection... params) {
             final Chat newChat = params[0].getChat(conversationID);
             final List<Message> newMessageList = Lists.newLinkedList(newChat.getMessages().values());
             Collections.sort(newMessageList, messageSorter);
             return new CurrentChat(newChat, newMessageList, newChat.getParticipants().size() > 2);
        }
```

For reference, the sorter I am using is:

```
private final Comparator<Message> messageSorter = new Comparator<Message>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final Message lhs, final Message rhs) {
        if(lhs.getSentDateTime() != null && rhs.getSentDateTime() != null) {
            return lhs.getSentDateTime().compareTo(rhs.getSentDateTime());
        }
        else if(lhs.getSentDateTime() == null & rhs.getSentDateTime() == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(lhs.getSentDateTime() == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
};
```

The exception that I get is an IndexOutOfBoundsException that occurs within the Collections.sort() call:

```
12-17 15:14:40.951    2270-2332/com.chat.android.communication E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; index=11
            at java.util.LinkedList.toArray(LinkedList.java:958)
            at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1890)
```

I have only seen this error occur one time and since the error was simply uploaded to my server from one of the application users, I don't have anything else to go off of.  Because of this, I wrote a separate unit test which creates a large number of Integers in a list, spawns several threads that add and remove items from the list and sort it, hoping to at least create the same error.  I did this because I suspected that re-using the same instance of the Comparator within my sort operation was the culprit.  However, this unit test runs fine with no issues.   The only time I run into any problems is if I *remove* the copying of the list prior to sorting.  If I do that, I easily run into concurrentModificationExceptions and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

My unit test I have been messing with in attempt to re-create the same stack trace:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting");

        Callback myCallback = new Callback();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[1000];


        int exceptions = 0;

        final MessageComparator messageSorter = new MessageComparator();

        List<Integer> tempList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            tempList.add(200-i);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);
            tempList.add(i);

            List<Integer> newList = new  ArrayList(tempList);
            Thread t = null;
            try {
            t = new Thread(new SorterThread(tempList, messageSorter));
            t.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                exceptions++;
            }
            threads[i] = t;

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Finished");
        System.out.println(exceptions);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to recreate the problem in my unit test so that I can ensure I fixed the problem, but at this point I have no idea what else may have caused it.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try recreating with `final List<Message> newMessageList = Lists.newLinkedList(newChat.getMessages().values());` and null values or empty values parameter

Comment: I altered my unit test to create a new linked list via google guava 18.0 and didn't have any issues with that method either.

Comment: You have a typo in your Comparator which may be throwing off the sorting algo resulting in the exception you see: `else if(lhs.getSentDateTime() == null & rhs.getSentDateTime() == null) {` need to change to `else if(lhs.getSentDateTime() == null && rhs.getSentDateTime() == null) {` (not the double ampersand).

Comment: @xpa1492 thank you for the reply.  That is definitely a bug, however, based on the error stack trace I posted, it doesn't look like I am even getting into the compare method.  It's gotta be something else.

Comment: Any other thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem with your code are the following lines:

```
final List<Message> newMessageList = Lists.newLinkedList(newChat.getMessages().values());
Collections.sort(newMessageList, messageSorter);
```

In Android (specifically API level 23, see [this link](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-23/blob/master/java/util/LinkedList.java)), when you call LinkedList's constructor using `Collection<E>` as argument, the following code is run:

```
      @Override
      public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> collection) {
         int adding = collection.size();
         if (adding == 0) {
            return false;
         }
         Collection<? extends E> elements = (collection == this) ?
                new ArrayList<E>(collection) : collection;

         Link<E> previous = voidLink.previous;
         for (E e : elements) {
            Link<E> newLink = new Link<E>(e, previous, null);
            previous.next = newLink;
            previous = newLink;
         }
        previous.next = voidLink;
        voidLink.previous = previous;
        size += adding;
        modCount++;
        return true;
   }
```

Hence, if the size of `collection` changes right after `int adding = collection.size()` is executed, then `elements` array will have an invalid size which causes `Collections.sort` throw an exception when `LinkedList.toArray()` is called. Synchronizing partially solves the problem, however, consider using another data structure or a copy instead. Possibly, the follow code might help:

```
ArrayList<Message> newMessageList =
Arrays.asList(
    newChat.getMessages()
           .values()
           .toArray(new Message[0]));
Collections.sort(newMessageList, messageSorter);
```